# Plotly Dash: Overflow into ellipses only one datatable column

Tags: python, plotly-dash

the example for overflowing text into ellipses for a dash datatable seems to apply to all columns that require it.
Is it possible to specify which columns I would like to apply this to?

```
app.layout = dash_table.DataTable(
    data=df.to_dict('records'),
    columns=[{'id': c, 'name': c} for c in df.columns],
    style_cell={
        'overflow': 'hidden',
        'textOverflow': 'ellipsis',
        'maxWidth': 0
    }
)
```

Say I want "column 1" to overflow into ellipses but not the rest.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `style_data_conditional` property to apply a given style only to certain columns, see the [Dash data table documentation on conditional formatting](https://dash.plotly.com/datatable/conditional-formatting). In your case the code would be something along these lines:

```
style_data_conditional=[{'if': {'column_id': 'column 1'}, 'textOverflow': 'ellipsis'}]
```